# My systemd slices aren't reporting info to systemd-cgtop

Tags: systemd, cgroups

I have a centos VM running via KVM on my Debian laptop.

This is what I see when I run systemd-cgtop:
[image]

I know I have a user,system,and machine slice, but I'm only seeing data from the machine slice.

I'm running chrome and youtube so I know stuff is going on in the user slice, but I don't see the user slice at all.

How can I get my other slices to report utilization in cgtop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible reason is that you have not enabled the `CPUAccounting` for the system slice.

Check if `/etc/systemd/system.conf` is defined with `DefaultCPUAccounting=yes` or define `CPUAccounting=yes` in `system.slice`.

Comment: I have the same issue on OpenSUSE. `DefaultCPUAccounting` didn't help. Setting `CPUAccounting=yes` in all slices indeed made `systemd-cgtop` report slices load but still didn't report any automatic sub slices nor individual services.